# JavaScript: Why isn't my clock working?

Tags: javascript

When I load my page, no clock appears no matter what I do. I have created two buttons. If I remove the button which refers to the `stopTime()` function which contains `clearTimeout(t);` then my clock appears. If I put the button back my clock won't work.

```
<body onload="getTime()">


  <script>

  var t;

  function getTime() 
  {  
     var time = new Date();

     var hour = time.getHours();
     var minute = time.getMinutes();
     var second = time.getSeconds(); 

     hour = checkTime(hour);
     minute = checkTime(minute);
     second = checkTime(second);

     var actualtime = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

     document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = actualtime;

     t = setTimeout(function(){getTime()},1000);
  }

  function checkTime(i)
  {
      if ( i < 10 )
          i = "0" + i;
      return i;
  }

  function stopTime();
  {
      clearTimeout(t);
  }

  </script>


</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked your debug window? Immediately it comes to my attention that you have a semicolon where one shouldn't be: `function stopTime();`

Comment: While you're at it, move your JavaScript code to inside the `head` element.

Comment: Also with your setTimeout, you don't need to create a function to call a function. Just pass that function to it instead. `t = setTimeout(getTime,1000);`

Comment: Using a fixed interval of `1000` means that the clock will slowly drift and occasionally skip a second. That can be fixed by setting the interval to just after the next full second, e.g. `setTimeout(getTime, 1020 - time.getMilliseconds());`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a syntax error here:

```
function stopTime();
{
    clearTimeout(t);
}
```

Take out the `;` at the end of your `function stopTime()`.

Fixing that, your code runs fine for me.

Comment: Whoops, thanks that solved it. I hate it when I don't see such a little error :(

Comment: @Grobi But you don't have to find it yourself. The browser will tell you. Just look in the console.

Answer (score 0):

there where javascripts error. 
fixed the js errors try the below code

```
var t;
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10){ i = "0" + i;}
    return i;
}

function stopTime(){
    clearTimeout(t);
}



function getTime() {
    var time = new Date();

    var hour = time.getHours();
    var minute = time.getMinutes();
    var second = time.getSeconds();

    hour = checkTime(hour);
    minute = checkTime(minute);
    second = checkTime(second);

    var actualtime = hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second;

    document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = actualtime;

    t = setTimeout(function() {
        getTime();
    }, 1000);
}
```